# Is "it started to grow arms" understandable here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, understanding

I write kinda fairy-tale, and there are two people who turned into other beings. When they begin to change into human form, I wrote that one sentence:

"In their stony bodies **it/there started to grow arms** (... so Kim could finally hug her own sister...)" - is it understandable that I mean that they are still in form of the other beings, but they begin to change into human (at that moment) starting with their arms? If no, how else could I write it or how can I get to know (about) how to write it in more slick way?
And I don't know what I can put instead of "it" or "there", if that "it" or "there" would be incorrect.

Comment: Without context, it's unclear what "it" refers to in your proposed sentence. Is there some entity inside them that is not part of them that is growing arms?

Comment: 'Their stony bodies started to grow arms'. You can speak of a being 'growing' an appendage, as in 'The deer grows antlers'.